# References for a statement on linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Suppose we have a linear system $\dot{x} = A x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is a constant matrix, such that all the trajectories of the system are bounded and bounded away from the origin (i.e., none of them converge to the origin). This I believe implies that all the eigenvalues of $A$ have 0 real parts and that $A$ is diagonalizable. I also believe that for this type of system, there exists a symmetric matrix $P$ such that $x^t P x$ is constant along the trajectories.

I am interested in this as I use it in my research. I have a proof of it, though it seems to be a rather simple result, and I would prefer to simply cite a reference for it.

Does anyone know of any references to these facts? (e.g., a book or paper that states/proves these statements)

Comment: This could be seen as a very simple instance of matrix-Riccati equations, a topic in optimal control.